# Cross-Origin Request Blocked: (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, html5-video, google-dfp, vast

I am trying to validate a VAST tag in different validators. It throws me this error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xml. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I can't figure out the problem because:

1. I have enabled CORS in my Amazon S3 bucket.(Done the configuration)
2. No errors are thrown for tags that were uploaded already while configuring the CORS in s3.
3. If I copy the xml manually and test it as VAST xml, it works fine.
4. I double checked on the urls for the files associated, everything is accesible and works fine.

What is the issue? Can't figure out the issue for  whole day now, please help.

Comment: You might want to share your S3 config, VAST and URIs. The question, as it is written right now, is hard if not impossible answered.

Comment: I didn't post the original question, but I have the same problem.  This is my S3 configuration.  I don't see any CORS headers for any request, though.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered this problem before. Usually the advertiser needs to place an * within their header. 
If this still is not the problem, then you are actually looking at an issue with the player and need to debug that.

Comment: Your answer is not very specific. Provide more details please. Read the SO guidelines before posting.